# Start GCM Service explicitly when application starts Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Is there any way to start the Google Cloud Messaging Service explicitly. Apparently after sometime (after 4 to 5 hours) my app stops receiving any messages from GCM. If I go to app and check in the running apps tab, I can no longer see the Message Service in my application. Is this normal?

Furthermore I think GCM is the most unreliable service for push notifications. I have encountered many a times an issue where I am not able to send a notification but if I start the application then I start recieving notifications.

Comment: The fact that the Service is killed, or even the application, is perfectly normal. They will be started again when the GCDM is received (provided the `AndroidManifest.xml` is correct). That said, I don't know why you don't receive GCM messages after some time.

Comment: The android manifest file is writtem properly. Otherwise I would not be receiving notifications in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are only two possibilities:

- GCM is down (unlikely)
- Your server doesn't send the messages to the correct device

  - either because it doesn't send message at all
  - or because GCM has changed the registration ID, and your application failed to handle this correctly (but it should if you followed the sample from the SDK)

Comment: Ok I checked some thing very odd. After some time I started sent a msg to my application and GCM did not start. Then when I started my application and then sent another message, GCM started working! There has to be a way to manually start GCM if it is turned off...